# activity not started on buttonclick?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
  Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
           final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
           TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
           b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     abc=ed.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);


                }
                 })
```

this is my mainactivity code i am starting another activity onbutton click but instead of that i am getting error and my app crashes can someone help me to remove this error/

```
02-23 14:20:06.557: E/AndroidRuntime(2732): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newpicker/com.example.newpicker.AnotherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this is my logcat

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

 static Context context;
   public boolean a;
    private DownloadManager downloadManager;
 static TextView tt1;
  String url="http://www.digitalmarketingbox.com/";
  private DownloadManager dm;
  String v1,v2;
   ArrayList<String> imageid = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> imagepath = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> playlist_content = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList();
     String i1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.showimages);
            //tt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView tt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.it);
            AnotherActivity.tt1.append(MainActivity.abc);

   }

    02-23 14:35:08.561: D/dalvikvm(4900): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-23 14:35:08.702: D/libEGL(4900): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-23 14:35:08.702: D/libEGL(4900): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-23 14:35:08.702: D/libEGL(4900): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-23 14:35:08.702: I/Adreno200-EGL(4900): <eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic AU_full_mako_PARTNER-ANDROID/JB-MR1-DEV_CL2961380_release_AU (CL2961380)
02-23 14:35:08.702: I/Adreno200-EGL(4900): Build Date: 12/10/12 Mon
02-23 14:35:08.702: I/Adreno200-EGL(4900): Local Branch: 
02-23 14:35:08.702: I/Adreno200-EGL(4900): Remote Branch: m/partner-android/jb-mr1-dev
02-23 14:35:08.702: I/Adreno200-EGL(4900): Local Patches: NONE
02-23 14:35:08.702: I/Adreno200-EGL(4900): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
02-23 14:35:08.742: D/OpenGLRenderer(4900): Enabling debug mode 0
02-23 14:35:12.936: D/AndroidRuntime(4900): Shutting down VM
02-23 14:35:12.936: W/dalvikvm(4900): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d10930)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newpicker/com.example.newpicker.AnotherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.example.newpicker.AnotherActivity.onCreate(AnotherActivity.java:41)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-23 14:35:12.946: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     ... 11 more
```

this is my full logcat

Comment: post the code for AnotherActivity (onCreate and global variables should suffice)

Comment: Post the complete error logcat log

Comment: Please check your resource name(s) is correct

Comment: Clean the project the let us know.

Comment: Do you have the target Activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Do you set the contentView before actually getting the button..

Comment: are u add the next activity in android mainfest file?just check?

Comment: you should provide the context correctly instead of giving v.getContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

> ```
>   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                  abc=ed.getText().toString();
>                 Intent intent=new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class);
>                 startActivity(intent);
>             }
>              });
> ```

And make sure that you have defined the `AnotherActivity` in your manifest.

Comment: Changing v.getContext() to this will make the Intent use the anonymous inner class' instance, and the code won't even compile.

Comment: i have defined the acitivity in menifest

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change this line of code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
```

into this:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

As you are Using View as an argument inside button function to handle button event listener. Hope it will help.

Comment: The problem is in the other Activity. Your solution does nothing to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

i have defined the textview as static above and trying to define it again as a normal one just checked it and the problem is solved thank you guys

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

  static Context context;
  public boolean a;
  private DownloadManager downloadManager;
  static TextView tt1;
  String url="http://www.digitalmarketingbox.com/";
  private DownloadManager dm;
  String v1,v2;
  ArrayList<String> imageid = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> imagepath = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> playlist_content = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList();
  String i1;
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showimages);
        tt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.it);
        //---tt1.append(MainActivity.abc);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me just yesterday. even tho i defined the activity inside the `Manifest` but i struggled to launch it. what i did was to check if i wrote the Class name probably on my manifest. and to check if its working, i'd to change it to become the `MainActivity` and it worked so i knew something is wrong. anyway i did make it work by using this

```
                if(Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Samsung") || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("samsung")){
            doAll();
            }else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Smaller.this.getApplicationContext(),ForOthers.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
              }
```

here is a something i'm checking when the user launches my app. forget it and just see the

```
YourClassName.this.getApplicationContext(),OtherAcitvity.class
```

Comment: i don't know what is the problem and it is making me mad,this same code was working perfectly fine yesterday what happened today i don't know